# Jinja ничего не отображает через цикл for. Не работает for в Jinja

Tags: html, sql, flask, jinja2, jinja

HTML код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

                    <div class="row">
                    {% block content %}
                        <!-- Latest Products -->
                        {% for post in posts %}
                        <div class="col-sm-4 sm-margin-b-50">
                            <div class="margin-b-20">
                                <div class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration=".3" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="Latest Products Image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'img/970x647/01.jpg') }}">
                                    <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="img/970x647/01.jpg" alt="Latest Products Image"> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h4><a href="#">{{ post['title'] }}</a> <span class="text-uppercase margin-l-20"></span></h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed tempor incdidunt ut laboret dolor magna ut consequat siad esqudiat dolor</p>
                            <a class="link" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <!-- End Latest Products -->
                    {% endblock %}
                    </div>
```

app.py код:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template

def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index-test/')
def index_test():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    posts = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM posts').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index-test.html')
```

init_db.py код:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')


with open('schema.sql') as f:
    connection.executescript(f.read())

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('First Post', 'Content for the first post', 'Description content for the first post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('Second Post', 'Content for the second post', 'Description content for the second post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('Third Post', 'Content for the third post', 'Description content for the third post')
            )

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

schema.sql код:

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

  CREATE TABLE posts (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      title TEXT NOT NULL,
      description TEXT NOT NULL,
      content TEXT NOT NULL
  );
```

Проблема в том что на сайте абсолютно пусто, хотя database.db не пуст. Как будто цикла for вовсе нету в html файле

Comment: Как минимум вы не передали `posts` в шаблон

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается я не только дибил но и слепой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в app.py должно глядеть так

```
return render_template('index-test.html', posts=posts)
```